# PHP : Неправильно работает функционал отрисовки даты и времени

Tags: php, дата, datetime, timezone

Ребят помогите найти ошибку в логике.
Есть строка которая хранит интервалы времени в разных временных зонах.После парсинга строки получив день и время надо его вывести по следующей логике:

> Код учитывал разные временные зоны

- если в строке день повторяется то написать его один раз а его
  интервалы времени перечислить в скобкахразделяя запятой.На данный момент `Mon` повторяется то есть должно быть отрисовано `MON (00:00 — 22:00, 23:00 — 24:00)`
- А если нет то написать день и его интервал `SUN 23:00 — 24:00`

То Есть в итоге рассчитывал получить результат в следующем формате:

```
SUN 23:00 — 24:00
MON (00:00 — 22:00, 23:00 — 24:00)
FRI 00:00 — 22:00
```

У меня `method byDay() class  timeBuilder` правильно выводить дату а вот `__toString` неправильно.Выводит всего лишь `FRI 00:00 — 22:00`

Помогите пожалуйста исправить логику.

```
<?php
    $token =  '{#daylyrange sun 17:00 - sun 24:00 tz-America/Chicago #}'
            . '{#daylyrange mon 00:00 - thu 16:00 tz-America/Chicago #}'
            . '{#daylyrange mon 17:00 - thu 24:00 tz-America/Chicago #}'
            . '{#daylyrange fri 00:00 - fri 16:00 tz-America/Chicago #}';

    $formattedTime = new timeBuilder($token);

    echo $formattedTime;//запрашивает магический метод  __toString,и выводит неправильно
    echo '<br><br>';


    //Эта часть неправильно обрабатывает
    $Days = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri');
    foreach ($Days as $day)
    {
        echo $day .' ['.$formattedTime->byDay($day).']<br><br>';
    }
    exit;
?>
```

**Class timeBuilder:**

> $Orapoxum перемнная указывайте на то что день поменялся

```
<?php
class timeBuilder
{
    private $token = '';
    private $times = array();
    private $intervals = array();
    private $baseTimezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
    private $customTimezone = null;
    public static function arraytostr($token)
    {
        $return = '';
        foreach ($token as $wday => $val)
        {
            $startH = strtotime($val['start']['hour'] . ':' . $val['start']['minute']);
            $endH = strtotime($val['end']['hour'] . ':' . $val['end']['minute']);
            if ($startH and $endH)
            {
                $return .= '{#day ' . $wday . ' ' . $val['start']['hour'] . ':' . $val['start']['minute'] . ' - ' . $val['end']['hour'] . ':' . $val['end']['minute'] . '#} ';
            }
        }
    }

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->customTimezone = new DateTimeZone($this->baseTimezone);
        $this->token = preg_replace_callback('(\{\#([^\#]+)\#\})', array($this, 'render_callback'), $token);

        $this->mergeinervals();
        $timeindex = 0;
        if (isset($this->times[$timeindex]))
        {
            if ($this->times[$timeindex]['type'] != 'range')
            {
                $this->times = array();
                $this->times[$timeindex]['start'] = $this->intervals[0]['start'];
                $this->times[$timeindex]['end'] = $this->intervals[0]['end'];
                $this->times[$timeindex]['type'] = 'day'; //range daylyrange day
                foreach ($this->intervals as $interval)
                {
                    $hasTime = false;
                    foreach ($this->times as $index => $time)
                    {
                        if (($time['start']->format('H:i') == $interval['start']->format('H:i') )and ( $time['end']->format('H:i') == $interval['end']->format('H:i')))
                        {
                            if (($interval['end']->format('N') == 5) && ( ($interval['start']->format('N') == 5)))
                            {
                                $this->times[$index]['end'] = $interval['end'];
                                $this->times[$index]['type'] = 'daylyrange';
                                $hasTime = True;
                            }
                            if ( ($interval['end']->format('N') != 5 ) && ( ($interval['start']->format('N') != 5 )))
                            {
                                $this->times[$index]['end'] = $interval['end'];
                                $this->times[$index]['type'] = 'daylyrange';
                                $hasTime = True;
                            }

                            if (!$hasTime)
                            {
                                if (($interval['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('N') == 5) and ( ($interval['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('N') == 5)))
                                {
                                    $this->times[$index]['end'] = $interval['end'];
                                    $this->times[$index]['type'] = 'daylyrange';
                                    $hasTime = True;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        elseif ($time['end']->format('H:i') == $interval['end']->format('H:i'))
                        {
                            if ($time['start']->format('H:i') < $interval['start']->format('H:i'))
                            {
                                $this->times[$index]['start'] = $interval['start'];
                                $this->times[$index]['end'] = $interval['end'];
                                $this->times[$index]['type'] = 'daylyrange';
                                $hasTime = True;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$hasTime)
                    {
                        $timeindex++;
                        $this->times[$timeindex]['start'] = $interval['start'];
                        $this->times[$timeindex]['end'] = $interval['end'];
                        $this->times[$timeindex]['type'] = 'day';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $out = '';
        $dayspart = '';
        foreach ($this->times as $intervals)
        {
            if ($intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('N') > 6)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ( !empty($out) )
                $out.= ',<br>';
            $endstr = $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('H:i');
            if ($endstr == '00:00')
            {
                $endstr = '24:00';
                $intervals['end'] = $intervals['end']->sub(new DateInterval('P0Y0DT0H1M'));
            }
            switch ($intervals['type'])
            {
                case 'range':
                    $out .= $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D H:i') . ' — ' . $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D H:i');
                    break;
                case 'daylyrange': // this
                    $outed_flag = false;
                    $Orapoxum = ($intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('H:i') > $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('H:i'));
                    // append same-day-range hours
                    if ($dayspart == $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D') . ' — ' . $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D'))
                    {
                        if ($Orapoxum) {
                            $add = '00:00 — ' . $endstr . ', ' . $intervals['start']->format('H:i') . ' — 24:00';
                        } else {
                            $add = $intervals['start']->format('H:i') . ' — ' . $endstr;
                        }
                        preg_match("#" . $dayspart . "[^(]+\([^)]+\)#", $out, $matches);
                        $match = $matches[0];
                        $match_moded = str_replace(')', ', ' . $add . ')', $match);
                        $out = str_replace($match, $match_moded, $out); // insert time range
                        $out = substr($out, 0, strlen($out) - 5); // remove comma
                        $outed_flag = true;
                    } else {
                        if ($intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D') == $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D'))
                            $dayspart = $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D');
                        else
                            $dayspart = $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D') . ' — ' . $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D');
                    }
                    if (!$outed_flag)
                    {
                        if ($Orapoxum)
                        {
                            $out .= $dayspart . '<span class="ltrspan"> (00:00 — ' . $endstr . ', ' . $intervals['start']->format('H:i') . ' — 24:00)</span>';
                        } else {
                            $out .= $dayspart . '<span class="ltrspan"><bdo dir="ltr"> (' . $intervals['start']->format('H:i') . ' — ' . $endstr . ')</bdo></span>';
                        }
                    }
                    if ($out == 'Mon<span class="ltrspan"> (00:00 — 22:15)</span>')
                    {
                        $out = ''; //Gidem vor vorija
                    }
                    break;
                case 'day':
                    if ($intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D') != $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D'))
                    {
                        $out .= $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D') . '<span class="ltrspan"> (00:00 — ' . $endstr . ') </div>';
                    } else {
                        $out .= $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D') . '<span class="ltrspan"> (' . $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('H:i') . ' — ' . $endstr . ') </div>';
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        $out = str_replace(array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'), array('[T]Mon[/T]', '[T]Tue[/T]', '[T]Wed[/T]', '[T]Thu[/T]', '[T]Fri[/T]'), $out);
        return $out;
    }

    public function byDay($day_of_week, $Timezone = null)
    {
        if (!$Timezone)
            $this->customTimezone = new DateTimeZone($this->baseTimezone);
        else
            $this->customTimezone = new DateTimeZone($Timezone);
        $Daystart = new DateTime($day_of_week . ' 00:00:00 ');
        $Y = $Daystart->format("Y");
        $m = $Daystart->format("m");
        $d = $Daystart->format("d");
        $Daystart->setTimezone($this->customTimezone);
        $Daystart->setDate($Y, $m, $d);
        $Daystart->setTime(00, 00, 00);
        if ($day_of_week == 'Sun') {
            $Daystart = $this->fixtime($Daystart, true);
        } else {
            $Daystart = $this->fixtime($Daystart);
        }
        $DayEnd = clone $Daystart;
        $DayEnd->add(new DateInterval('PT24H'));
        $boolDaystart = true;
        $boolDayEnd = true;
        if (count($this->intervals) == 0)
        {
            return '—';
        }
        $this->intervals[count($this->intervals) - 1]['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone);
        $this->intervals[0]['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone);
        if ($Daystart > $this->intervals[count($this->intervals) - 1]['end'])
            $boolDayEnd = false;
        if ($DayEnd < $this->intervals[0]['start'])
            $boolDayEnd = false;
        $TempDaystart = $Daystart;
        $TempDayEnd = $DayEnd;
        $outIntervals = array();
        $index = 0;
        if (($boolDaystart) AND ( $boolDayEnd)) {
            foreach ($this->intervals as $intervals) {

                $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone);
                $intervals['end']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone);
                if ($Daystart < $intervals['start']) {
                    $TempDaystart = $intervals['start'];
                } else
                    $TempDaystart = $Daystart;

                if ($DayEnd > $intervals['end']) {
                    $TempDayEnd = $intervals['end'];
                } else
                    $TempDayEnd = $DayEnd;

                if (($TempDayEnd > $TempDaystart)) {
                    $outIntervals[$index]['start'] = $TempDaystart;
                    $outIntervals[$index]['end'] = $TempDayEnd;
                    $index++;
                }
            }
            $out = '';
            $outIntervalsmerged = array();
            $domerge = false;
            foreach ($outIntervals as $index => $interval) {
                if ($domerge) {
                    $domerge = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if (isset($outIntervals[$index + 1])) {
                    if ($interval['end'] == $outIntervals[$index + 1]['start']) {
                        $custominterval = array();
                        $custominterval['start'] = $interval['start'];

                        $custominterval['end'] = $outIntervals[$index + 1]['end'];
                        $outIntervalsmerged[] = $custominterval;
                        $domerge = true;
                    } else {
                        $outIntervalsmerged[] = $interval;
                    }
                } else {
                    $outIntervalsmerged[] = $interval;
                }
            }
            $outIntervalsmerged = $this->getMinrange($outIntervalsmerged);
            foreach ($outIntervalsmerged as $interval) {
                if ($out != '')
                    $out .=', ';
                $Daystart = $interval['start'];
                $DayEnd = $interval['end'];

                $startstr = $Daystart->format('H:i');
                $endstr = $DayEnd->format('H:i');
                if ($endstr == '00:00') {
                    $endstr = '24:00';
                }
                $out .=$startstr . ' — ' . $endstr;
            }

            if ($day_of_week == 'Fri') {
                $satinterval = $this->byDay('Sat', $this->customTimezone->getName());
                if ($satinterval != '—')
                    $out = $out . ', <div class="outday"> [T]SAT[/T] ' . $satinterval . '</div>';
            }
            if ($day_of_week == 'Mon') {
                $satinterval = $this->byDay('Sun', $this->customTimezone->getName());          
                if ($satinterval != '—') {
                    $out = '<div class="outday">[T]SUN[/T] ' . $satinterval . ',</div>' . $out;
                }
            }
            if (empty($out))
                $out = '—';
            return $out;
        } else {
            return '—';
        }
    }

    private function getMinrange($intervals)
    {
        //TODO Tuftelem to asxati mincheb ban horinem
        $count = count($intervals);
        if ($count > 1) {
            $interval1 = $intervals[0];
            $interval2 = $intervals[1];

            if (($intervals[1]['start'] > $intervals[0]['start'])and ( $intervals[1]['start'] < $intervals[0]['end'])) {
                $intervals[0]['start'] = $intervals[1]['start'];
            }
            if (($intervals[1]['end'] < $intervals[0]['end'])and ( $intervals[1]['end'] > $intervals[0]['start'])) {
                $intervals[0]['end'] = $intervals[1]['end'];
            }

            if (($intervals[0]['start'] == $intervals[1]['start'])and ( $intervals[0]['end'] == $intervals[1]['end']))
                unset($intervals[0]);
        }
        return $intervals;
    }

    private function fixtime($time, $agr = false)
    {
        $Endweek = new DateTime('Sun 00:00:00');
        $Y = $Endweek->format("Y");
        $m = $Endweek->format("m");
        $d = $Endweek->format("d");
        $Endweek->setTimezone($this->customTimezone);
        $Endweek->setDate($Y, $m, $d);
        $Endweek->setTime(00, 00, 00);

        if (($time > $Endweek) or ( $agr))
            $time->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
        return $time;
    }

    private function render_callback($matches)
    {
        $timezone = $this->baseTimezone;
        $val = explode(' tz-', trim($matches[1]), 2);
        if (isset($val[1])) {
            $timezone = $val[1];
        }
        $val = explode(' ', trim($val[0]), 2);
        $out = 'UNKNOWN';   
        $timeindex = count($this->times);
        $i = count($this->intervals);

        switch ($val[0])
        {
            case 'day':
                $range = explode('-', $val[1]);
                $time1 = new DateTime(trim($range[0] . ' ' . $timezone));
                $time2 = new DateTime($time1->format('D') . ' ' . trim($range[1] . ' ' . $timezone));
                if ((trim($range[1]) == '24:0')or ( trim($range[1]) == '24:00')) {
                    $time2->add(new DateInterval('PT24H'));
                }
                $time1 = $this->fixtime($time1);
                $time2 = $this->fixtime($time2);
                $this->times[$timeindex]['start'] = $time1;
                $this->times[$timeindex]['end'] = $time2;
                $this->times[$timeindex]['type'] = $val[0];
                $this->intervals[$i]['start'] = $time1;
                $this->intervals[$i]['end'] = $time2;
                $out = $val[1];
                break;
            case 'range':
                $range = explode('-', $val[1]);
                $time1 = new DateTime(trim($range[0] . ' ' . $timezone));
                $time2 = new DateTime(trim($range[1] . ' ' . $timezone));
                $time1 = $this->fixtime($time1);
                $time2 = $this->fixtime($time2);
                $this->times[$timeindex]['start'] = $time1;
                $this->times[$timeindex]['end'] = $time2;
                $this->times[$timeindex]['type'] = $val[0];

                $this->intervals[$i]['start'] = $time1;
                $this->intervals[$i]['end'] = $time2;

                $out = $val[1];
                break;
            case 'daylyrange':
                $range = explode('-', $val[1]);
                $time1 = new DateTime(trim($range[0] . ' ' . $timezone));
                $time2 = new DateTime(trim($range[1] . ' ' . $timezone));
                if ($time2->format('H:i') == '00:00') {
                    $time2->add(new DateInterval('PT24H'));
                }
                $time1 = $this->fixtime($time1);
                $time2 = $this->fixtime($time2);
                $this->times[$timeindex]['start'] = $time1;
                $this->times[$timeindex]['end'] = $time2;
                $this->times[$timeindex]['type'] = $val[0];
                $datestart = clone $time1;
                $datestart = $this->fixtime($datestart);
                $dateend = new DateTime($time1->format('D') . ' ' . $time2->format('H:i') . ' ' . $timezone);
                if ($dateend->format('H:i') == '00:00')
                {
                    $dateend->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                }
                $dateend = $this->fixtime($dateend);
                while ($dateend <= $time2) {
                    $this->intervals[$i]['start'] = clone $datestart;
                    $this->intervals[$i]['end'] = clone $dateend;
                    $i++;
                    $datestart->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                    $dateend->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                }
                $out = ($val[1]);
                break;
        }
        return $out;
    }

    private function mergeinervals() {
        $count = count($this->intervals);
        $rechech = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $excount = count($this->intervals);
            if ($i >= $excount)
                break;
            $tempinterval = $this->intervals[$i];
            if (isset($tempinterval)) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
                    $excount = count($this->intervals);
                    if ($j >= $count)
                        break;
                    if (isset($this->intervals[$j])) {
                        if ($this->intervals[$j]['start'] == $this->intervals[$i]['end']) {
                            $this->intervals[$i]['end'] = $this->intervals[$j]['end'];
                            unset($this->intervals[$j]);
                            $this->intervals = array_values($this->intervals);
                            $rechech = true;
                        }
                        if (isset($this->intervals[$j])) {
                            if (($this->intervals[$j]['start'] == $this->intervals[$i]['start']) and ( $i != $j)) {
                                if ($this->intervals[$i]['end'] != $this->intervals[$j]['end'])
                                    $this->intervals[$i]['end'] = max(array($this->intervals[$j]['end'], $this->intervals[$i]['end']));
                                unset($this->intervals[$j]);
                                $this->intervals = array_values($this->intervals);
                                $rechech = true;
                            }
                            if (isset($this->intervals[$j]) && (($this->intervals[$j]['end'] == $this->intervals[$i]['end']) and ( $i != $j)))
                            {
                                if ($this->intervals[$i]['start'] != $this->intervals[$j]['start'])
                                    $this->intervals[$i]['start'] = min(array($this->intervals[$j]['start'], $this->intervals[$i]['start']));
                                unset($this->intervals[$j]);
                                $this->intervals = array_values($this->intervals);
                                $rechech = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($rechech)
            $this->mergeinervals();
        return $this->intervals;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну куча `if` и строк кода говорит что вы храните данные не так как нужно (

Comment: @Naumov  Да этот код работал раньше ,сейчас время поменялось (летнее ,зимнее ) и что то не работает

Comment: попробуйте локализовать проблему, ибо трудно читать код состоящий из большого количества if

Comment: @Naumov Честно говоря не знаю где проблема чтоб локализовать,ото бы и сам решил.

Comment: В примере одни интервалы, а в "правильном" выводе-примере - другие. Это как?

Comment: @Other Для Разных timezone время выводится по разному.Тут выводится по 'Europe/Berlin'.Что тут странного.Если запустить тот код то и вы увидите эти интервалы

Comment: `"Вопрос актуален для широкой аудитории"` - неправда ведь..

Comment: Это ровно тот случай, когда имеет смысл устроить коду экстерминатус и написать заново, по человечески

Comment: @rjhdby Да я так и сделаю,Напишу заново .Но все равно не факт что лучше получится :(. По этому обратился к местному СО Думал что помогут

Comment: А зачем в коде идет работа с временной зоной ? В вопросе ни слова ни сказано, что интервал должен выводится в некой другой зоне. А раз так то выводить видимо следует в той же зоне, а тогда ее анализ не требуется вообще.

Comment: @Mike Зачем, почему,это говнокод и так далее.Можно до бесконечности обсуждать и обсирать код.Есть код который работал исправно.Временные метки поменялись и он стал глючить.есть баг в код и его надо найти.Я в принципе нашел,но не уверен до конца

Comment: "в принципе нашёл" - не поделитесь догадкой? В Вашем лапше-коде вряд ли кто будет разбираться, иначе ответили бы.

Comment: @Sergey Невозможно что то исправить в коде, не зная точно, что он должен делать на самом деле. Я упомянул временную зону в коде потому, что мне кажется что вы не до конца описали задачу. Я подозреваю, что временная зона там используется не спроста. И без разъяснения как минимум этого момента в текущем коде невозможно выявлять какие либо ошибки потому что не известно какое поведение является ошибкой, а какое запланировано

Comment: @Mike Все что знал и как поднимал вопрос ,изложил в своем вопросe.Там нечего добавлять.Формат вывода определил,А вывести не могу правильно,поскольку неправильно высчитываю время перехода дней ( летнее-зимнее | зимнее-летнее  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да код действительно что надо:)

> Прошу обратить на моё решение как на подсказку.

Я обратил внимание что в методе `__toString` вы пропускаете 7 ой день,то есть воскресенье

> if ($intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('N')
>   {
>       continue;
>   }

То Есть уже плохо,так как вы хотите его выводить.

Можно тут воспользоваться вашим metodom `byDay()`

```
if ($intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('N'))
{
    $sun = $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->format('D');
    $out = strtoupper($out .= $this->byDay($sun);).' ';
    $out .= $this->byDay($sun);
    $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->modify('+1 day');
}
```

У вас получилось на стыке дня вы eго пропускаете и ничго не длаете.

> $intervals['start']->setTimezone($this->customTimezone)->modify('+1
>   day');

Там где случается переход дня надо ему подсказать что это уже следующий день.

[DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php)

В основном проблему решил.Уверен что дальше никому не захочется копаться в этом,Так что пользуясь подсказкой и решите временно вашу задачу.

**И вообще совет:**
Не пладить много сущностей,и если код становится нечитабельным и трудно поддерживаемым то уже есть повод задуматься о его рефакторинге.Такие коды обречены.Не пытайтесь в цикле решить сразу несколько задач.Всегда записывайте в какие нибудь промежуточные переменные(легче дебажить), а уж потом выводить .

Comment: Не понимаю как но это работает . Честно говоря боюсь его применить на продакшене.И так отхватил люли за свой г-код.Сейчас буду тестить.Спасибо огромное что не поленились и помогли мне.Совeта буду придерживаться :)